# javascript eval works one way but not the other, why?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am trying to use eval function for dynamic assignment. I know it is bad practice and have modified the code to not use eval. Still though, I don't understand why it worked one way but not the other.

Here is what worked:

```
onFilterChosen(filterEmited: string, kind: string) {
    eval("this.dbParams." + kind + " = filterEmited");
}
```

What didn't work:

```
onFilterChosen(filterEmited: string, kind: string) {
    eval("this.dbParams." + kind + " = " + filterEmited);
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the second approach?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It works both ways but there are different pieces of code passed to it in your examples.

Comment: Thanks axiac & iota for responding. I understood with the answer provided by likle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, there must be a variable which has the name of the value of filterEmited. Let's make an example, we call the function:

```
onFilterChosen('filter', 'abc');
```

will result in this JS to be executed in the first example:

```
this.dbParams.abc = filterEmited
```

which works, because the parameter is called `filterEmited`.
whereas in the second example this will be executed:

```
this.dbParams.abc = filter;
```

and since there is no variable "filter" it might crash.

btw. emitted is spelled with two t's!

Comment: Oh, that was so dumb of me... I have been looking at this code for so many days and kind of made up my mind that it will only work the first way - not the second.. Now I know that I should have substituted the value of variable (like I did for 'kind'). Thanks for pointing it out... This question doesn't deserve to be on StackOverflow, I think.

And... Emited should be spelt with two t's? I'll correct the variable name as well.

Comment: @TKtheLazyGuy we all have these times, and your question was upvoted so I think it's perfectly fine!